Can not rename a file in desktop by pressing F2
Note that this is not a Laptop, but a Desktop computer.
If I highlight a file on the Desktop, press F2 and simply try to rename it by simply pressing the arrow keys (left or right), it will close the renaming hovering box and move on the Desktop to the next file on the Desktop. Instead of moving the cursor between the highlighted name of the file I press the F2 key on. This is using the latest update that includes Gnome 46.2
So the issue only happens if you press the arrow keys, for example you have the word spongevob and you want to correct the V in there instead of writing the whole thing, the moment you press the arrow keys it fails as described above.
If this is not a setting but a bug, to which app should I assign this issue to? mutter? gnome-shell? ubuntu 24.04? nautilus/file?

I've just tried this, and I have the same issue - except on mine, the arrow keys do move the cursor. The cursor moves, however a split-second later the rename box closes and the selection moves to the next item on the Desktop.
